# Turn CKEDITOR into a pdf

Tags: html, pdf, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor (http://ckeditor.com/) on my site.  I would like for users to be able to push a button to generate a PDF.  Currently, I have them press the print function that came with ckeditor, which brings up the print window and from most browsers they can generate a PDF.  But I want to make it simplier.  I know that generating PDFs from html is difficult, but are there any simple solutions to do this (generate a PDF from the html that ckeditor gives)?

I've heard of a few solutions like fpdf, dompdf and html2pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `iText` and `XMLWorker` to create PDF from HTML code.

```
public void createPDF() throws DocumentException, IOException 
{
    String fileName="path you want to create the document";
    Document document=new Document();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    document.open();
    String finall="<h1>This is a Demo</h1>";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(finall.getBytes());
    XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter,document, is);
    document.close();

}
```

Here we are using XML worker so all your tags should be closed correctly. You need `iText` and `XMLWorker` JAR files.Hope this will help you.

Comment: can you give an example?  and link to those jar files please

Comment: also itext is very expensive.  are there any cheaper options that are just as good?

Comment: You can download XMLWorker from the following link http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/files/

Comment: And Itext from http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/ if my answer helps you just accept it :)

Comment: i downloaded and uncomressed those folders and put them on my server, but is there more i need to do?  i get an error when i run the code

Comment: wait this is java.  id rather not use java on my site.  is there a php solution?

Comment: I am not sure about PHP coding, you can check these links. http://www.phpjabbers.com/create-pdf-file-with-php-php36.html http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1414-how-to-generate-a-pdf-with-php/

Comment: ok java seems like the best solution, but im not so good with it so could you please provide an example with this code in an html file? thanks